# Didn't type password into CLI with ChromeOS, now I can't do any commands in Ubuntu

Tags: command-line, 16.04, password, chroot, chromeos

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 with Chroot and CLI on ChromeOS. When I was prompted to answer a password, I hit Enter (without typing a password) and when I try to do commands it asks for a password. I then try to type nothing, but it says it's invalid. Can I get some help with this?

Comment: A valid password is required. <enter> is not a valid password. Create a valid password for your account: [How do I reset a lost administrative password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password)

Comment: How do I boot into recovery mode if Ubuntu is installed with ChromeOS?